# GAS: Set Chart Vertical Axis > Show Axis Line

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

I'm using some script to calculate min and max values for the Vertical Axis depending on the chart's value range, which works fine.

```
  chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.min',minVal)
    .setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.max',maxVal)
    .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
```

However, every time I use this, the Vertical Axis > Show Axis Line checkbox in the Chart Editor gets disabled. I've searched for an Option at [Line Chart Options](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/chart-configuration-options#line-config-options) to set this in the function, but there doesn't seem to be one.

I've also tried to use a Macro when enable this setting, to see in the resultant code which Option is being set, and another Macro when disabling it, but both macros are identical, and do not show any such Option.

Anyone have a suggestion on how to set (or retain) this chart option?

Answer (score 0):

You can't show/hide the vertical axis lines with Apps Script, but what you can do is request this feature in [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).